# Ubuntu c++: The easiest way to display a 3D mesh and a 2D image together?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, 3d, 2d, mesh

I've been fighting with several libraries (irrlicht, Ogre3D etc) and falling between either too complex libraries or too complex installation guides.
I'd appreciate some pointers to how to achieve what the title suggests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going for simplicity of setup and use, I'd recommend you [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/). It not only allows you to render both in 3D and 2D, but has a lot of other functionality including scripting in c++.

If you're looking for a more lightweight solution, though not as easy, you can try using [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/). It is quite easy to set up - just install [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and start with their OpenGL template. Although it is much harder to learn and use, it is very developing.

If you don't really need to use c++, you can use [Unity](https://unity.com/). Although its interface is exposed through c#, its not very hard to learn for a c++ programmer. I also find it easier to use than Unreal Engine.

I would also reccomend [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/), which would probably the most perforamant of all of them, but well, you wanted a "simple" solution.